# How to make popup message after successful form submission without page reload?

Tags: javascript, node.js, connect-flash

I have a contact form at the end of my website. When a user makes successful POST request to my Nodejs Server, I wanted to display a message saying something like:

> Message Sent Successfully

I tried to use `connect-flash` npm package but the problem is that the contact form is at the bottom of the page and when the POST request is successful, even though I get the flash Message saying "Message Sent Successfully", since the page reloads a user has to scroll all the way down to see the flash message.

Comment: Instead of submitting your form with post, send an ajax request to the server. When the server acknowledges this request, then show the message to the use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bootstrap class

> fixed-top

.

```
<div class="fixed-top"> your flash message </div>
```

Comment: I don't want to add Bootstrap library to display one font message. Thanks though. Maybe it will help someone else